# use .block() with complex matrix eigen lib

Tags: c++, complex-numbers, eigen3

when i would like to use `block()` with `MatrixXcd` In and `levyhorni`:

```
levyhorni=In.block(0,0,h/2,w/2);
```

is correct or for every part of complex is correct?

```
levyhorni.real()=In.real().block(0,0,h/2,w/2);
```

and same for `.imag();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the first statement is correct. You can even simplify it to:

```
levyhorni = In.topLeftCorner(h/2,w/2);
```